# Google searches with "link:" don't seem to work

Tags: hyperlink, google-search

According to https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/2466433?p=adv_pages_similar&hl=en&rd=1, `link:` should *find pages that link to a certain page*, but that feature doesn't seem to work.

Even the example they give (`link:youtube.com`) gives me no results at all (*did not match any documents*).

Answer (score 0):

[answering to myself]

The Google help page I mentioned is outdated. Should be `linkto:`, not `link:`.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work for me, it just interprets the text in the URL. I'm guessing that they may have removed the original `link:` feature rather than changed it.

Comment: @James `linkto:` works for me. For example, when I search for `linkto:youtube.com`, I get 405,000,000 results, but `link:youtube.com` gives me 0 results.

Comment: I tried it with the website of the company I work for and it returned irrelevant results based on the word "link" and the words in the URL. That is why you get loads of results for YouTube; it is looking for the pages that mention YouTube rather than those that specifically link to it.